# Си.Двухпутевое слияние. Где ошибка?

Tags: c, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием, merge

Почему то в файле выдаются нулевые значения, но я не могу понять почему..

Здесь я осуществляю двухпутевую сортировку слиянием.В файл записываю данные о кол-ве сравнений для каждого набора 100, 200 и т.д.

И нужно ли мне еще где-то считать сравнения и нужно ли считать операции копирования в другой массив, чтобы потом в итоге получить график зависимости n log n?

Код самой сортировки приведен в самом низу.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void merge( int *a, int lb, int split, int ub, int* count) {

  int pos1=lb;
  int pos2=split+1;
  int pos3=0;
  int *temp = (int*)malloc((ub+1) * sizeof(int)); 

  while (pos1 <= split && pos2 <= ub) {
    if (a[pos1] <= a[pos2]){
      temp[pos3++] = a[pos1++];
      (*count)++;
    }
    else{
      temp[pos3++] = a[pos2++];
      (*count)++;
    }
  }

  while (pos2 <= ub)
    temp[pos3++] = a[pos2++];
  while (pos1 <= split)
    temp[pos3++] = a[pos1++];


  for (pos3 = 0; pos3 < ub-lb+1; pos3++)
  
    a[lb+pos3] = temp[pos3];
    //free(temp);
}

void mergeSort(int *a, int lb, int ub, int* count) {
  long split;

  if (lb < ub) {
    split = (lb + ub)/2;

    mergeSort(a, lb, split, count);
    mergeSort(a, split+1, ub, count);
    merge(a, lb, split, ub, count);
  }
}

int main() {
    FILE *f =  fopen("stat510.csv", "w");
    int n = 100;
    srand(time(NULL));        
    while (n <= 10000) {
        int count=0;
        int t , s;                             
        for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
            int *arr;
            arr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof *arr);  
            int c = 0;
            int* count = &c;
            srand(time(NULL));
            for ( s = 0; s < n; s++) {
                arr[s] = rand() % 50;
            }
            mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1, count);
            free(arr);
        }
        int st = count / 5;
        fprintf(f, "%d ; %d\n", n, st);
        if (n < 1000) {
            n += 100;
        } else {
            n += 1000;
        }   
    }
    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void merge( int *a, int lb, int split, int ub, int* count) {

  int pos1=lb;
  int pos2=split+1;
  int pos3=0;
  int *temp = (int*)malloc((ub+1) * sizeof(int)); 

  while (pos1 <= split && pos2 <= ub) {
    if (a[pos1] <= a[pos2]){
      temp[pos3++] = a[pos1++];
      (*count)++;
    }
    else{
      temp[pos3++] = a[pos2++];
      (*count)++;
    }
  }

  while (pos2 <= ub)
    temp[pos3++] = a[pos2++];
  while (pos1 <= split)
    temp[pos3++] = a[pos1++];


  for (pos3 = 0; pos3 < ub-lb+1; pos3++)
    a[lb+pos3] = temp[pos3];
}

void mergeSort(int *a, int lb, int ub, int* count) {
  long split;

  if (lb < ub) {
    split = (lb + ub)/2;

    mergeSort(a, lb, split, count);
    mergeSort(a, split+1, ub, count);
    merge(a, lb, split, ub, count);
  }
}

void arrprint(int *arr, int n) {
    printf("%d", *arr);
    int i;
    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++) printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n = 10;
    int *arr = NULL; 
    arr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof *arr); 
    int c = 0; 
    int* count = &c; 
    srand(time(NULL));
    int s;
    for ( s = 0; s < n; s++ )
        arr[s] = rand() % 50;

    arrprint(arr, n);
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1, count);
    arrprint(arr, n);

    free(arr);
    puts("");

    printf("Comparison count: %d\n", *count);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В каждом цикле с сортировкой

```
int count=0;
int t ;
for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
  int c = 0;
  int* count = &c;
  mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1, count); }
```

вы меняете переменную `c`. Но потом тело цикла заканчивается и всё по-новой. Вы результаты никуда не сохраняете. Можно избавиться от лишних переменных `c` и `count` (*второй экземпляр как указатель*).

```
int count=0;
int t ;
for (t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
  // int c = 0;
  // int* count = &c;
  mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1, & count); }
```

Comment: Действительно..спасибо :) 
Извинюсь, но..где-то еще что-то нужно подсчитывать?Или всё в порядке?